# CasperJS to get top 5 Yahoo Mail

Tags: javascript, html, email, phantomjs, casperjs

I am able to `login` & `logout` to Yahoo Mail using CasperJS, but unable to fetch email details like `Data`, `Subject`, `EMail body` & `Sender Name`.

There is work around to get

- `Sender Name` using `class="name first"`
- `Subject` using `class="subject bold"`
- `Date` using `class="date bold"`

But there is no clue found to find `EMail body`.

Issues is, i need to click on the EMail div and then EMail body is then loaded, i am unable to click the EMail div.

I am trying to click that EMail div using `javascript`.

Can someone help me to find way to get EMail body in Yahoo Mail.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: "I am trying to click that EMail div using javascript." Please, show what you've done already. [How to create minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also - is it not simpler to get mail via IMAP and then process it? (obviously you have login requisites)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `casperInstance.mouseEvent()`. note - `mouseEvent` accepts only valid CSS3 Selectors.

```
casperInstance.mouseEvent('click', 'CSS3 Selector');
```

It will click the respective element.

This will work optimally than clicking via javascript inside `evaluate()`.